# how to use ajax to search in paginated pages

Tags: javascript, ajax

I created a simple js script that will filter names in a list. The issue I'm facing now, is if the list paginates I can't pull up the names without refreshing. 
Is there any thing I can do with ajax to look into the other pages, and populate them, without paginating?
The URL looks like this www.mysite.com/my_slug?page=1

Any help would be great. Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#filter-search").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $(".filter-data").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: The only valid answer to your detailed question is: *maybe*.

Comment: Can you add the "simple js script" you mention to your question to help add a little context?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that if you're doing the filtering on the client side JS code that all of the names are available in the JS code (whether they are on another page or not)? If so, then you need to find out where the object or array is that stores ALL names and not just the ones on the current page. This is usually known as the "data source". Once you find this, then you can call the filter function on the data source instead. If you don't have a data source yet, then you need to create one in order for this to be possible.

Alternatively, you can handle this logic on the server side instead. Depending on what kind of app you're building this might be a better approach so that all of the names, filtering, etc. are all maintained on the server side and the client only cares about displaying the names on the current page.